# Django: How to rollback (@transaction.atomic) without raising exception?

Tags: django

I'm using Django's command to perform some tasks involving database manipulation:

```
class SomeCommand(BaseCommand):
    @transaction.atomic
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        # Some stuff on the database
```

If an exception is thrown during execution of my program, `@transaction.atomic` guarantees rollback. Can I force this behavior without throwing exception? Something like:

```
# Doing some stuff, changing objects

if some_condition:
    # ABANDON ALL CHANGES AND RETURN
```

Comment: I suspect there is no way to do this. You will have to do with raising an exception and catching it quietly. I've created a temp-exception subclass, catch it and pass, all inside the `atomic` block.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

[`transaction.set_rollback`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.set_rollback) can do this.

```
class SomeCommand(BaseCommand):
    @transaction.atomic
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        # Doing some stuff, changing objects
        if some_condition:
            # Return, rolling back transaction when atomic block exits
            transaction.set_rollback(True)
            return
```

Quoting from [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.set_rollback):

> Setting the rollback flag to `True` forces a rollback when exiting the innermost atomic block. This may be useful to trigger a rollback without raising an exception.

Answer (score -2):

Just call `transaction.rollback()`.

> Calling transaction.rollback() rolls back the entire transaction. Any uncommitted database operations will be lost.

You can see example in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/transactions/#transaction-rollback).

Comment: Using `transaction.rollback()` together with `transaction@atomic` is forbidden, so if exception is actually thrown somewhere, rollback won't happen.

Comment: More than that, django will throw an error when calling `rollback()` within a `transaction.atomic` block. This is simply not a solution.

Comment: To expand upon what @reformy said, from the docs: `In order to guarantee atomicity, atomic disables some APIs. Attempting to commit, roll back, or change the autocommit state of the database connection within an atomic block will raise an exception.`

Answer (score -3):

You can manage the code execution to raise or not an exception:

```
try:
    if some_condition:
        with transaction.atomic():
            # Your logic here
except Exception, e:  # An example, use a explicit error
    # Show something friendly instead of a exception
```

Comment: In this code, the "your logic here" section will be committed to DB. No rollback here.

Comment: I don´t see in which parallel universe you observe that. I've been using the same approach and it works as expected with transactions rolled back when an exception raises.